# Show/hide navigation on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

This jquery show navigation menu when you scroll up page 0px up (in right-way). But trying to show after 200px (on page scroll-up), means not showing right way, want show and hide after 200px when scroll up page.

**Jquery:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fbr320y/1/)

```
// Script
lastScroll = 0;
$(window).on('scroll',function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll === 0){
        $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
    } else if(lastScroll - scroll > 0) {
        $(".nav").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
    lastScroll = scroll;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
Sticky top navigation bar
</div>
<div class="wrap">
<h3>Some filler text</h3>
Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet mollit ball tip occaecat brisket cupidatat meatball capicola. Capicola rump turducken, elit shankle cupidatat pastrami duis fatback. Sint occaecat kielbasa labore pastrami corned beef. Sunt swine bacon, fugiat dolor aute anim jerky nostrud et venison shankle consectetur boudin landjaeger.
Pork chop sed turkey aute, duis corned beef pariatur short loin proident culpa. Capicola filet mignon fugiat corned beef shank ea, commodo doner adipisicing eu salami. Doner laboris pariatur beef ribs non id. Andouille eu meatball consectetur ham hock. Ea dolore cillum cow pork loin aliquip leberkas id est corned beef dolore t-bone. In salami jerky cupidatat et.
</div>
```

Any advice? Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fbr320y/1/).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#One of the way i have found:

```
// Script
    var lastScroll = 0;
    var scrollUpStart = 0;
    $(window).on('scroll',function() {

        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(scroll === 0){
            // we are at the top
            $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
        } else if(lastScroll > scroll) {
            // we are scrolling up

            // we check if we have started scrolling up
            if (scrollUpStart < scroll) {
                // if we just started scrolling up, we set the 'marker'
                scrollUpStart = scroll;
            }

            if (scrollUpStart - scroll > 200) {
                $(".nav").addClass("darkHeader");
            }

        } else {
            scrollUpStart = 0;
            // we are scrolling down
            $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
        }
        lastScroll = scroll;
    });
```

Example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fbr320y/20/) :)